# Can users see comments on deleted answers?

Tags: support, answers, comments, deleted-answers

Technically, this is a very rare occasion, but I was struggling to find an official statement to this:

Now, I know that [deleted answers are visible to >10k rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126348/are-my-deleted-answers-visible-to-others), but I was wondering, recently I commented on my own answer, that I then later deleted.

Before the deletion, I did however @tag an user:

[image]

Will the user be able to read the comment after deletion / be at least notified or will the comment/notification be automatically lost with the answer deletion?

*I presume the latter*

---

Note: Yes, in this case notifying the user is absolutely unnecessary, I just do wonder for future reference what would be the expected behaviour.

Comment: I did get notifications for `@`-tagged comments on posts that were deleted, so, as far as I know, yes, that user will get notified, and the first part (~90 characters?) of the comment will be readable in the notification tab, for some amount of time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They *will not* be notified<sup>*</sup>, but they *will* be able to view the comments if they happen to return to the post and have 10K (or some other status that lets them view that particular post when deleted).

<sup>*</sup>The exception here is that mobile apps will tend to keep notifications even if they're later removed from the inbox... Which can lead to weird effects where you'll be able to read the first sentence but no more as it disappears when you try to load the full inbox.

Comment: To clarify the behavior on web: there will be a brief notification available between the moment of the comment and moment of the deletion of the post. And that reminds me that it may be cool to add support for in-browser push notifications in the future. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API

Comment: @Cœur Ugh @ browser push notifications plz no!